# Libreoffice "English sentence checking" option missing

Tags: 14.04, libreoffice, writer

Libreoffice documentation says that there must be an "English sentence checking" page in Options > Language settings, but it is missing in my Libreoffice Writer (4.2.6.3) on Ubuntu 14.04. Grammar check did not even work on a default installation, although spellcheck worked fine. Simple grammar check started working after installation of `libreoffice-lightproof-en` package, but still no "English sentence checking" option. How can I get full grammar check functionality that Libreoffice documentation refers to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the Libreoffice documentation in 4.2 may be a little dated since the release of 4.3.  Grammar checking is supported as an extension to LibreOffice, and needs to be installed from within Libre.  The pool of available grammar checkers is not large, and you might examine [LanguageTool](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/languagetool), or [After The Deadline](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/after-the-deadline-grammar-style-and-misused-word-detector).  [Lightproof](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/lightproof-editor) is unsupported and does not work in Libre version 4+

Comment: This is frustrating. The primary reason to use MS Word *instead* of Libre Writer is that the MS Word O365 Grammar checker is much more advanced. It's 2021, and I still can't find a decent grammar checker for Libre Writer (formerly OpenOffice/StarOffice Writer). To date, Microsoft still refuses to endorse Wine or allow MS Office to "properly" run on GNU\Linux without a bloated Windows Virtual Machine. VMs are fine, but I don't really have as much RAM or as many cores as I would like on my host machine.  The online MS Word 365 has minor limitations that the desktop windows version does not.

Answer (score 0):

In Libre)ffice go to `Tools`>`Extension Manager`. Then select `Writer Extensions` under Extension Releases.

Thereafter, select the extension of your choice (in this case LT - Language Tool) and 'voila!.

[image]